# Distinct values when already using count and group by

Tags: mysql, sql

This is currently the SQL query I am using:

```
SELECT DAY(time), count(id) 
FROM users 
WHERE time >= now() - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
GROUP BY DAY(TIME)
```

But it includes repeated email values. How can I get the count by day for only unique email address entries?

Thanks

Comment: use `count(distinct id)`

Comment: where is email in your query?

Comment: SELECT DAY(time), count(distinct email) FROM userWHERE time >= now() - INTERVAL 7 DAY  GROUP BY DAY(TIME)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
SELECT DAY(time), count(distinct email) 
FROM userWHERE time >= now() - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
GROUP BY DAY(TIME)
```